# Do relative server side redirects respect the protocol?

Tags: http, redirect, https, server-side

I've got a Jetty based java app that does a **relative** server side redirect:

e.g. redirects to the relative url:

/page2.html

The page that's redirecting from is served over `https`, but the redirect ends up being served as an `http` response

`https://someDomain.com/page1.html`

redirects to

`http://someDomain.com/page2.html`

Should I be able to use a relative url or not? We have a proxy server that's doing some rewriting - is it responsible, or is this just not supported in server side redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HTTP allows a redirect to a relative URL, and it should be using the same protocol as the URL that is doing the redirect, per [RFC 3986 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5).  If Jetty or the proxy is doing something different than it is not complying with established standards.

Comment: Turns out it's Jetty that's rewriting the relative url to an absolute url - and since it doesn't know it's being served securely (the load balancer is securely loaded, not the nodes), then the url gets rewritten as an absolute URL -> with an http:// scheme. More info [here](http://osdir.com/ml/java.jetty.general/2002-06/msg00188.html), and [in the src, where it gets turned into an absolute uri](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/1a0eb64a1fabccd6d4b2990e1a6864db6ac2019b/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/MovedContextHandler.java#L113)

Comment: Note this [unit test](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/063ad177b510b238aa51396030870e7d9aef0b8e/tests/test-integration/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/test/rfcs/RFC2616BaseTest.java#L1087) that implies testing for an absolute URI when the request was a relative redirect (I think ;-)

Comment: and from the RFC - [here's a super nice PSUEDOCODE](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.2) of the suggested algorithm to manage resolving what a relative URI points to, and it seems like Jetty is doing it right - resolve to an absolute URI. And [here's a super nice example in the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.4) showing sample relative urls and how they should be resolved.

Comment: and for what I finally used to fix the problem with Jetty was to simply configure Apache to let Jetty know that it was being proxied, [as I detailed in the answer to a very related question ;-) on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/627302/38435)